HTTPStatusError: Client error '404 Not Found' for url 'http://localhost:11434/api/chat'

# setup llm & embedding model
                llm=Ollama(model="llama2")
                embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding( model_name="BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5", trust_remote_code=True)
                # Creating an index over loaded data
                Settings.embed_model = embed_model
                index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs, show_progress=True)

                # Create the query engine, where we use a cohere reranker on the fetched nodes
                Settings.llm = llm
                query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming=True)

 streaming_response = query_engine.query(prompt)

i run : streamlit run app.py
When I chat, an error appears
HTTPStatusError: Client error '404 Not Found' for url 'http://localhost:11434/api/chat'

Are you sure you have pulled the model? This error is because Ollama cant found the model you are requesting for.
I had the same issue but my case was a typo in the model name.
I had this code:
Settings.llm = Ollama(model="defog-llama3-sqlcoder-8b", request_timeout=1000.0)

And the correct one is:
Settings.llm = Ollama(model="mannix/defog-llama3-sqlcoder-8b", request_timeout=1000.0)

Be sure you run this code in the terminal before using Ollama
ollama run llama2

And then be sure you have the server running.
ollama serve

If this run correctly you should be able to use the sentence
llm=Ollama(model="llama2")

Be sure you download the Ollama from: https://ollama.com/
